# GLFW3 & GLEW Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, opengl, glew, glfw

I got linked opengl32, glew32 and glfw3. Everything  is fine till run app.
I inited glfw 1st, next I created context and inited glew. There's no error.
Problem shows only when I'm trying to use OpenGL 3.2 functions like glBindBuffer, I got segmentation fault, but address is setted, can anybody help me?

```
// *** ADDED BY HEADER FIXUP ***
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
// *** END ***
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// (c) Janusz Ganczarski
// http://www.januszg.hg.pl
// JanuszG@enter.net.pl
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// identyfikator obiektu programu
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
GLuint program;

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// identyfikator obiektu bufora z danymi tablicy
// wierzchołków - współrzędnymi wierzchołków kwadratu
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
GLuint vertexBuffer;

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// identyfikator obiektu tablic wierzchołków
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
GLuint vertexArray;

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// współrzędne wierzchołków trójkątów składających się na kwadrat
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
GLfloat position[2 * 3 * 2] = {
    -0.5f, -0.5f,
    0.5f, -0.5f,
    0.5f,  0.5f,

    -0.5f, -0.5f,
    0.5f,  0.5f,
    -0.5f,  0.5f
};

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// funkcja generująca scenę 3D
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void DisplayScene()
{
    // czyszczenie bufora koloru
    glClear ( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

    // włączenie obiektu tablic wierzchołków
    glBindVertexArray ( vertexArray );

    // włączenie shadera
    //glUseProgram( program );

    // narysowanie danych zawartych w tablicach wierzchołków
    glDrawArrays ( GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 2 * 3 );

    // wyłączenie shadera
    glUseProgram ( 0 );

    // wyłączenie obiektu tablic wierzchołków
    glBindVertexArray ( 0 );
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// zmiana wielkości okna
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void Reshape ( int width, int height )
{
    // obszar renderingu - całe okno
    glViewport ( 0, 0, width, height );
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// inicjalizacja stałych elementów maszyny stanu OpenGL
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void InitScene()
{
    // kolor tła - zawartość bufora koloru
    glClearColor ( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f );

    // wczytanie shaderów i przygotowanie obsługi programu
    //AttachVertexShader( program, "kwadrat_vs.glsl" );
    //AttachFragmentShader( program, "kwadrat_fs.glsl" );

    // konsolidacja programu
    //LinkProgram( program );

    // generowania identyfikatora obiektu tablic wierzchołków
    glGenVertexArrays ( 1, &vertexArray );

    // utworzenie obiektu tablic wierzchołków
    glBindVertexArray ( vertexArray );

    // generowanie identyfikatora obiektu bufora
    glGenBuffers ( 1, &vertexBuffer );

    // utworzenie obiektu bufora wierzchołków (VBO)
    glBindBuffer ( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer );

    // załadowanie danych obiektu bufora wierzchołków
    glBufferData ( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof ( position ), position, GL_STATIC_DRAW );

    // pobranie indeksu atrybutu wierzchołka o nazwie "inPosition"
    //  GLuint positionLoc = glGetAttribLocation( program, "inPosition" );

    // zdefiniowanie tablicy wierzchołków
    // glVertexAttribPointer( positionLoc, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL );

    // włączenie tablic wierzchołków
    // glEnableVertexAttribArray( positionLoc );

    // wyłączenie obiektu tablic wierzchołków
    glBindVertexArray ( 0 );
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// usunięcie obiektów OpenGL
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void DeleteScene()
{
    // usunięcie obiektu programu
    glDeleteProgram ( program );

    // usunięcie obiektu bufora wierzchołków
    glDeleteBuffers ( 1, &vertexBuffer );

    // usunięcie obiektu tablic wierzchołków
    glDeleteVertexArrays ( 1, &vertexArray );
}


static void error_callback ( int error, const char* description )
{
    fputs ( description, stderr );
}
static void key_callback ( GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods )
{
    if ( key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_PRESS ) {
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose ( window, GL_TRUE );
    }
}

int main ( void )
{

    GLFWwindow* window;
    glfwSetErrorCallback ( error_callback );
    if ( !glfwInit() ) {
        exit ( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    glfwWindowHint ( GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3 );
    glfwWindowHint ( GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2 );
    glfwWindowHint ( GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE );
    glfwWindowHint ( GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE );

    window = glfwCreateWindow ( 800, 600, "Simple example", NULL, NULL );

    if ( !window ) {
        glfwTerminate();
        exit ( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent ( window );

    GLenum err = glewInit();
    if ( GLEW_OK != err ) {
        exit ( 1 );
    }


    glfwSetKeyCallback ( window, key_callback );


    InitScene();

    while ( !glfwWindowShouldClose ( window ) ) {
        int width, height;
        glfwGetFramebufferSize ( window, &width, &height );

        DisplayScene();

        glfwSwapBuffers ( window );
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
    glfwDestroyWindow ( window );
    glfwTerminate();
    exit ( EXIT_SUCCESS );
}
```

Comment: Post some code, especially where the seg fault happens.

Comment: @pwny added code sorry for comments

Comment: Where's the seg fault happening?  Can you remove as much code as possible and still reproduce the problem?  Having a minimal example (Without the foreign language comments preferably) will help us help you!

Comment: when app uses any 3.2 functions, like glBindBuffer, glBindVertexArray, etc..

Comment: You don't seem to be including `glew.h` before the GLFW header as specified in their FAQ (http://www.glfw.org/faq.html#215__can_i_use_glew_with_glfw).  I'm actually surprised your code compiles since you call GLEW function without having the header included...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing

```
glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
```

before you call glewInit(). Otherwise, it will crash when you draw from vertex arrays.